# PHP loop back through an if statement after SQL update

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out a way to loop back through an if statement if the user fills in the the missing fields that updates the database? I was thinking of setting the header location back on it's self but I don't think that will work. Any suggestions please?

```
     <?php
        if(!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start();  }

        if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
            header("location: ../login.php");
            exit;
        }

        require_once "../config.php";

        $key = $_SESSION["key"];

        if (empty($key)) { 

        $example = $website = "";
        $example_err = $website_err = "";
        $conn = $link;
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

            if(empty(trim($_POST["example"]))){
                $example_err = "Please enter a valid key.";
            } else{
                $example = trim($_POST["example"]);
            }

            if(empty(trim($_POST["website"]))){
                $website_err = "Please enter website URL.";     
            } else{
                $website = trim($_POST["website"]);
            }

            if(empty($website_err) && empty($example_err)){   
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET website=?, example=? WHERE id=?");
                $stmt->bind_param("sss", $param_website, $param_example, $param_id);
                $param_website = $website;
                $param_example = $example;
                $param_id = $_SESSION["id"];
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
                $conn->close();
                if($stmt){
                  *DO SOMETHING HERE*
                } else{
                    echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                }
            }
        }
        } else{
        echo "Success!";
}?>
```

Comment: Please update your question to clarify what  "loop back through an if statement" means. Which if statement, for what purpose? What is the user supposed to see/do? `*DO SOMETHING HERE*` <- what kind of something are you trying to do?

Comment: @AD7six I’m trying to get it so it recognises that the session value of “key” has now got a value (because the user has just submitted the form which fills that in) so when it goes through the if empty statement again it is no longer empty and instead goes to the else logic where it echos “Success!”. Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: There's nothing in the question populating `$_SESSION["key"]` - so `because the user has just submitted the form which fills that in` isn't happening. Note that php code is only executed once per http request so I don't know what is meant by `it goes through the if empty statement again`. The question is simply unclear/confusing as written.

Comment: @AD7six It's tricky to explain. From a higher view the flow would be, the user logs in on the previous page > they are sent to this page > then if they are missing the "key" in session then they are asked to fill out a form which stores it > once that it is filled in and submitted then they are shown the rest of the page and the form goes away

Answer (score 0):

If the form is on the same page, please set the form action as

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

and if not in the same page, please replace the following:

```
*DO SOMETHING HERE*
```

with

```
header("Location:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn’t solve the problem, I’ve just added a comment on the main thread to answer AD7six which may help your answer